# can't emulate the click event on the span in Google Drive

Tags: jquery, click, html

I am trying to simulate mouse click on a triangle in the Google Drive, which the expand the list of folders, using jQuery, loading to the page dynamically with a scriptlet, but it does not work.

the item that I click with the mouse (from http://drive.google.com) looks like

```
<span type="expand" class="goog-inline-block doclist-icon navpane-expand-icon doclist-folder-triangle-collapsed goog-tree-row-icon-hover" id=":3u.tfvtn" role="presentation"></span>
```

but when I try to send him a click () is not working - nothing changes!

```
$(".navpane-expand-icon").click();
```

Trying to send click() to any parent elements up to the div with big list of types - also dont work.

Please, tell me, what am I doing wrong?

//Using Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m & jQuery 1.10.2 but think that this in not important

Comment: `.click()` is for left click, not right click. If you want to detect right clicks, it will be a little more complicated.

Comment: oh, shi, im make a mistake... really i need normal **left** click :)

Comment: what isn't working exactly?

Comment: looks like send click() via jQuery not the same as really click with mouse pointer. im run `$(".navpane-expand-icon").click();` in Chome Console, and take output `[<span type="expand" class="goog-inline-block doclist-icon navpane-expand-icon doclist-folder-triangle-collapsed goog-tree-row-icon-hover" id=":3u.tfvtn" role="presentation"></span>]` (such as result of plant search-query, without .click() ) and webpage not changes.

Comment: I need to check the source of jquery. But if I remember right triggering an event with jquery does not create a real event, it only simulates the native behavior for event listeners registered with jquery.

Comment: That you see the result set in console is normal. Most of the jquery methods are chainable (returning itself when called)

Comment: maybe im not understand, but simular code `$(".doclist-name-wrapper").last().click()` work prefect and making visual changes on the page = display check near filename, as should, but yes, its also show me simular output)

Comment: Because the implementation of google does not use jQuery, triggering event with jQuery may work on some elements and would not work on others. The reason for this is how jQuery emulates the triggering of events.

Comment: thank you for support! what do you recommend - change this question, or reopen new with ask - how make tree of folders opened after load page?

Comment: Hi Anton, did you find a solution to your question?
I want to do the same with js or jQuery - open tree of folders in Google Drive.